# What command is used for currrent price/tick?

Tags: pine-script

In the wiki I see `open`, `close`, `high`, `low` but nothing for the current tick.

Im trying to use `crossunder(x, y)` where `x` is a line charted and `y` is the current price/tick.

What command do I use for current price?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Close variable is current price in trading view.

close = current price

close[1] = last candle close price

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

open, close, high, low return values of the current being handled bar. So for realtime bar these words referred to the current 'tick' data.